# Newtonsoft.Json Deserialize failure with long pathname

Tags: json, vb.net, serialization, json.net

```
Dim fileName As String = "C:\TEMP\json\Main API\Sound.json"

Dim jsonFile As String = File.ReadAllText(fileName)
TextBox2.AppendText(jsonFile)

Dim c As mTest = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of mTest)(jsonFile)
TextBox2.AppendText(c.mName & vbCrLf)
```

In my code example the file is loaded and displayed inside a TextBox. The string is then deserialized and the results mName string is printed to the TextBox. This is all very good.

Now if i change fileName to "C:\Projects\Visual Studio\Gideros Document Manager\Gideros Document Manager\bin\Debug\json\Main API\Sound.json" (a rather lengthy filename to be sure) then the file is loaded and displayed in the TextBox but it is NOT deserialized!

I (being a simple minded chap) cannot understand how it can actually load the file and display it but not process it any further, since it loaded it must have everything it requires to perform the deserialization right?. Even if I put it in a try,catch block it does not give any exception, it just fails to deserialize (but still loads and displays it just fine). Shouldn't it throw an exception if it couldn't deserialize it??

Comment: You are confused to be sure.  The file name is used by `System.Io.File` to read the file into the string.  JSON.NET acts on the string.  If the "long" path name was the blame it would be a failure of the NET framework.  Most likely you are dealing with 2 files with different text (or something else entirely which we cant possibly know with no code at all).

Comment: The file in the folder "c:\temp\..." has been copied and pasted from the folder with the long path name so is not different . As I said, the file is loaded as a string with both paths but the deserializer will only deserialize the resulting string from loading the file from the short path.

Comment: JSON.NET is not using the long pathname at all.  If there was a problem with long names, we would all know about it.  Even if there was a bug in `Io.File` it would not contaminate, infect JSON.NET.  Your problem is elsewhere but using a project folder for input data is folly because those folder wont exist when deployed.

Comment: I have my data there for testing only. I don't know why it doesn't work which is why I asked here is all. The fact remains that the string is loaded in both cases (both are the same string)  without error but the one resulting from the long path name does not deserialize, go figure I suppose.